# In Django, what is the best way to manage both a mobile and desktop site?

Tags: python, css, django, mobile, templates

I'd like everything to function correctly, except when it's mobile, the entire site will used a set of specific templates.

Also, I'd like to autodetect if it's mobile. If so, then use that set of templates throughout the entire site.

Comment: The problem is that for most mobiles a 1 on 1 mapping does not cut it. Mobiles screen estate (discouting IPhones and other Androids) are much smaller than traditional PCs and necessitate specific views (like breaking a PC view into 2/3 chunks). Also some functionalities can be painful on mobiles / blackberries (browsers quirks...). I wish you the best of luck nonetheless, and hope others will be able to answer the question with good cues :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have two sets of templates, one for mobile, one for desktop. Store the filenames in a pair of dictionaries, and use the `User-agent` header to detect which set should be used. Also allow manual selection of which site to use via a session entry.

Answer (score 1):

If you place a class on your body (Django uses something similar to specify what column style to use), you could use the same templates but simply use different stylesheets.  I'm not sure what main differences you are using separate templates for, but this might allow you to cut down on re-coding the templates multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

best practice: use [minidetector](http://code.google.com/p/minidetector/) to add the extra info to the request, then use django's built in request context to pass it to your templates like so.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def my_view_on_mobile_and_desktop(request)
    .....
    render_to_response('regular_template.html', 
                       {'my vars to template':vars}, 
                       context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

then in your template you are able to introduce stuff like:

```
<html>
  <head>
  {% block head %}
    <title>blah</title>
  {% if request.mobile %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/styles/base-mobile.css">
  {% else %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/styles/base-desktop.css">
  {% endif %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="navigation">
      {% include "_navigation.html" %}
    </div>
    {% if not request.mobile %}
    <div id="sidebar">
      <p> sidebar content not fit for mobile </p>
    </div>
    {% endif %>
    <div id="content">
      <article>
        {% if not request.mobile %}
        <aside>
          <p> aside content </p>
        </aside>
        {% endif %}
        <p> article content </p>
      </aricle>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different strategies.

If you've a lot of views that renders to template files for the web version, and don't want to rewrite all views checking if the request is coming from a mobile user-agent, you'd be better writing a Middleware.

A workflow could be like this:

```
def process request:
  if from_mobile:
    settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS=settings.TEMPLATE_MOBILE_DIRS
  else:
    settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS=settings.TEMPLATE_WEB_DIRS
```

There is only a little problem here: As Django Documentation reports, it's not correct to change settings at runtime: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime

So you may want to call

```
django.conf.settings.configure(default_settings, **settings)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends heavily on the type of your target audience. If you target for modern mobile browsers equivalents to their desktop counterparts (such as WebKit-based), all you need is specific stylesheet with appropriate [media query](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1) (you are basically designing for low-res rather than mobile).

Totally different strategy is needed if your site (e.g. airline schedules) must to be accessible widest possible range of mobile devices, some of running very old / limited browsers. Then custom (html) templates may be easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [mobilesniffer](http://code.google.com/p/mobilesniffer/) and [django-bloom](http://code.google.com/p/django-bloom/) to see if they fit your purposes.